# What Font is Used on This Packaging for the Text Reading "GUB"?

Tags: font-identification

What Font is Used on This Packaging for the Text Reading "GUB"?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: At that angle it is very difficult to see the proportions and angles. Do you have an image which shows an orthographic view of the packaging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This name logo is copied from another ad:

[image]

No proper answers in 2 weeks. I'm afraid it's a drawing. Some font might be used as a starting point, which is a common practice. But the letters ave got so radical edits that no font identifier service can decide the original.

I guess it was a heavy square font (fontzillion and dafont have many of them). Then the text was skewed and scaled wider and a bridge was drawn between G and U and then 2 more bridges between U and B. Finally some jut or bevel is modified or inserted to make it unclear which was the original font. That's because some font licenses prohibit using the font in a logo.